# How do I parse this string easily?

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

So I want to extract data from something on the form:

"San Diego"--"San Antonio" [1319]

I want to extract both of the cities names and the number at the end in brackets[]. If the city is one word there is no "" like in this example:

Toledo--Springfield [677]

Right now I'm using str.split("--") and then str.split(" ["). However the latter is not poosible and if I try to use split(" ") it will split in the middle of two word cities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex seems to be appropriated:

```
"?(.*?)"?--"?(.*?)"? \[(.*?)]
```

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"?(.*?)\"?--\"?(.*?)\"? \\[(.*?)]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\"San Diego\"--\"San Antonio\" [1319]");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Prints:

```
San Diego
San Antonio
1319
```

---

**Regexp explanation**

- `"?` means *"a `"` or not"*
- `.*?` means *"any string"*
- the parentheses capture the data between them, that's why afterwards, we can access them with `m.group(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! I've wanted to understand regex for a long time but never gotten the grip of the more advanced stuff, like this. Can you explain what does what in that expression?

Comment: You have to double slash to escape "[" but not "]"?

Comment: @Alex `]` has a *"meta meaning"* only if preceded by an unescaped `[`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your answers! You have been very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

After split by -- then check by using contains() method for " if it is true then split by space and [ .

Answer (score 1):

you can also use StringTokenizer in alternative to regex, in StringTokenizer you can specify delimiters next to each other, here assume you want -- and [ as delimiters, so just write --[ in delimiter section

```
String input="\"San Diego\"--\"San Antonio\" [1319]";
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(input, "--[");
while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) 
{
    System.out.println(tok.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: How does it know that "--" and "[" are different delimiters when they are just written after another "--["?

Comment: i dont know the back-end exactly, but it will figure it out somehow

Comment: Ok, thats good to know. So the rule is that if it matches any part of the string in it a delimiter?

Comment: i guess so, because in that way it works. btw as i know split() method works in same way too